# Run PHP unit test with multiple database drivers

Tags: php, database, pdo, phpunit, drivers

In a library I'm writing, one can supply a PDO instance that is used for any data persistence. A number of drivers are supported, say MySQL & SQLite. The library itself includes some files that perform SQL queries, which I want to test (using phpUnit). Hence I want to run a general (driver-independent) unit test, one time for each driver.

Internet did not bring me a clear best-practice solution, so these are the approaches I've come up with so far:

1. Use a dataProvider with ['mysql', 'sqlite'] and test on this; however its usage will than be limited to one test function only, which I dislike.
2. Set up each database connection in `setUpBeforeClass` for each of the drivers, and in each test loop through these and perform the tests. From a OOP standpoint this also is not a good alternative, not to mention having to set up multiple connections to different drivers at the same time may be quite resource intensive.
3. Create an abstract general unit test class with an abstract `setupConnection()` method. This class can than be extended with a proper database connection, for each of the required drivers. This seems the most viable option, however with a lot of files/classes to test in this way (more than 10.. well not a lot, but sufficiently many) this becomes a tedious and dirty approach to this problem.

Ideally, I sought for a way to say to phpunit 'Run this unit test file with these drivers'. Is this at all possible in a neat way? Or otherwise, what would be the alternatives?

Comment: If you want to test one class, option 3 seems reasonable.  If you want to test your entire application, then it seems you should just run the tests multiple times with different environments.  You can supply different phpunit configurations or set up a CI service like TravisCI that runs in various environments/versions/db servers.